# Tool to identify app's data/code most susceptible to memory performance

Tags: linux, memory, profiling

Context:
-- embedded platform running Linux with some static RAM which is declared about 3 times faster then the rest of RAM (dynamic). The amount of this fast memory is 512kB and the official name is eSRAM. (Details not important for this post: Galileo board, information on eSRAM and relevant kernel API: https://communities.intel.com/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/22488-102-1-26046/Quark_SWDevManLx_330235_001.pdf)
-- eSRAM can be used by an application with some support from the kernel---a simple driver that allocates kernel memory on its behalf, overlays the memory with eSRAM (this is done in physical space) and mmaps it to app's virtual memory space. This was tested and confirmed to work as expected.

Problem:
Identify which sections of app's data (and possibly code) to map into eSRAM to achieve optimum performance gain. A suitable analysis tool is required.

After some search I'm not sure if any existing tool is actually suited to this task. Currently my best bet is to develop a specialized Valgrind tool. But maybe there is already something in the ecosystem to start with. Any advice/information is welcome even if, for instance, a tool is kind of partially suited etc.

P.S.
Full analysis should probably take a lot of factors into account, like:
-- memory access patterns (cache performance)
-- changes over time (one could consider eSRAM paging)
...

Comment: I have taken a look at `Valgrind Cachegrind`. It can collect data about data cache reades and data cache writes. And `cg_annotate` can report `Line-by-line Counts` for you program. Can it be useful for you to find variables in your program that cause most operations with data cache and in this way to identify data that can benefit most from moving to quick memory? http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html#cg-manual.line-by-line

Comment: This is a very good pointer! I haven't dug into Cachegrind yet, but you are absolutely right! Basically what I am interested in are cache misses and if I could align them with data in the source, then it looks like exactly the info I need. So maybe the solution is Cachegrind and some postprocessing. Thanks a lot for this remark!

Comment: Probably, you are interested in `D cache reads` (Dr) and `D cache writes` (Dw), or even (Dr+Dw). In that way you can find a place in your code which does most (Dr+Dw) and try to move this place in your quick memory.

Comment: Or rather D1mr+D1mw is exactly what I'm interested in.  Or even C*D1mr+D1mw with some coefficient since read misses probably cost more.

Comment: The cache on the platform is 16kB unified (both I & D) single level cache with 16B lines (if I got the docs right https://communities.intel.com/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/21826-102-2-25118/Intel%20Quark%20Core_DevMan_001.pdf). Hence there is hope for some improvement by using eSRAM for critical data/code.

Answer (score 1):

I have taken a look at `Valgrind Cachegrind`. It can collect data about data cache reades and data cache writes. And `cg_annotate` can report `Line-by-line Counts` for you program. Can it be useful for you to find variables in your program that cause most operations with data cache and in this way to identify data that can benefit most from moving to quick memory? http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html#cg-manual.line-by-line

Probably, you are interested in D cache reads (Dr) and D cache writes (Dw), or even (Dr+Dw). In that way you can find a place in your code which does most (Dr+Dw) and try to move this place in your quick memory.